# Dereference function interface argument when argument is a pointer

Tags: go, pointers

When my function is given an interface argument that is a pointer I would like to update the pointer to something else (a* = b*). If the function argument is not an interface and is instead a pointer, this works fine.

Given the following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type demoInterface interface {
    GetName() string
}

type demoStruct struct {
    name string
}

func (d demoStruct ) GetName() string  {
    return d.name
}

func Update(d1 demoInterface)  {
    fmt.Println(d1)
    d2 := demoStruct{name: "bob"}
    d1 = &d2
    fmt.Println(d1)
}

func main() {
    d1 := &demoStruct{name: "frank"}
    fmt.Println(d1)
    Update(d1)
    fmt.Println(d1)
}
```

The output is

```
&{frank}
&{frank}
&{bob}
&{frank}
```

However I would actually expect

```
&{frank}
&{frank}
&{bob}
&{bob}
```

If I replace the Update function signature to accept a *demoStruct instead of a demoInterface it works as expected.

Is there a way to get this to work as expected when the functions signature is an interface rather than a pointer.

Thanks.

Comment: You could return the interface from that method.

Comment: No, as the interface value is a copy. But if you store a pointer in the interface this works (but of course you than cannot simply do a `d1 = d2`, you have to reach inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* need this, it could be one of the rare cases where a pointer to an interface may make sense. Here's your example modified with that:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type demoInterface interface {
    GetName() string
}

type demoStruct struct {
    name string
}

func (d demoStruct ) GetName() string  {
    return d.name
}

func Update(d1 *demoInterface)  {
    fmt.Println(*d1)
    d2 := demoStruct{name: "bob"}
    *d1 = d2
    fmt.Println(*d1)
}

func main() {
    d1 := demoInterface(demoStruct{name: "frank"})
    fmt.Println(d1)
    Update(&d1)
    fmt.Println(d1)
}
```

Note that since `Update` takes `*demoInterface`, we can't just pass in `*demoStruct` (Go has no type covariance), so we have to convert the struct to the interface first.